# Is it possible to add a ground to a vacuum?

Tags: electrical

I have an electronics vacuum that is not grounded. I feel this keeps it from adequately performing its primary function in a desirable way. Can I replace the cord with a grounded cord, and tap the cord to a case ground or something similar?

Comment: *why* do you feel that the lack of ground keeps it from *"adequately performing it's primary function in a desirable way"*

Comment: It sounds like you need it to be grounded for ESD reasons...why not take it back and get a vacuum that's properly grounded?

Comment: Are you concerned that this "electronics vacuum" would build up a static charge that could damage delicate electronic components?

Comment: If this is designed to be an "electronics vacuum" and was sold as a device for cleaning out computers, why do you think grounding is needed? Don't you think this would be accounted for by the engineers who developed the vacuum?

Answer (score 4):

Not being grounded is not going to affect the way the vacuum cleaner functions. In fact, most vacuums I've had/used are not grounded. They are mostly made from nonmetallic parts and insulated in such a way that grounding isn't needed or impossible to achieve.

Now, if you're using an ungrounded vacuum to clean electronics, computer motherboards, etc.and are worried about static charges, then by all means you could remove the two conductor cord and install a 3 conductor cord and a three prong plug.

Comment: Just curious - once a 3 conductor cord is added, what does he attach the ground wire to inside the vacuum? Not being snarky here, honestly asking. Since the appliance is not designed to have a ground, there won't be provisions inside it for attaching a ground, right? No insult intended to the OP, but since he didn't know if this was possible, she probably doesn't have the electronics knowledge to add a ground path to the device - I should as heck don't!

Comment: @FreeMan  The OP would have to improvise and hook it up to the metal casing, the motor mount, or some other metal area.  I think the OP wants to use a standard vacuum for electronics cleaning and wants to modify it rather than get a electronics vacuum with a ground.

Comment: kinda my point, JACK. He'd be improvising and that seems... unsafe for someone with limited electronics knowledge. Also, in the OP, she mentioned that it's an "electronics vacuum", so I think that particular assumption is incorrect, though it's a side note.